# C++ why does the binary file read skips to the end

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have a 178 MB FORTRAN unformatted binary file that I am reading with C++ and storing it in an Eigen Matrix.  I have read the file with FORTRAN and MATLAB to confirm that I understand the values in the file.  The first record in the file is the size of the matrix.  After that each record begins with 3 integers.  These integers contain the column and row where the data begins and the number of numbers to read.  This is followed by the single precision numbers themselves.

Here is my code:

```
std::ifstream infile("MSFILE", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if(!infile)
{
    std::cout << "Mode shape .f12 file (MSFILE) not found\n";
    exit(1);
}

int r_size1; // size of each record read
int r_size2; // size after reading for comparison

int cols, rows;
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&r_size1), 4);
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cols), 4);
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&rows), 4);
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&r_size2), 4);

if (r_size1 != r_size2)
{
    std::cout << "Error reading MSFILE\n";
    exit(1);
}

MatrixXf data(rows, cols);
data.setZero();

int * vals = new int[3]; // vals holds i_col, i_row and i_word for each record
float * tempf; // pointer to array of floats that holds the data from the file

// Read in the record, and continue through the file
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&r_size1), 4);

while (!infile.eof())
{
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (vals), 12);
    tempf = new float[vals[2]];
    int buf_size = vals[2] * 4;
    // read the data from the file
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (tempf), buf_size);

    // write the float array into the matrix
    data.col(vals[0] - 1) = Map<VectorXf>(tempf, rows);

    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&r_size2), 4);

    if (r_size1 != r_size2)
    {
        std::cout << "Error reading MSFILE\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    delete tempf;

    // finish out by reading the next record size...this will also force EOF
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&r_size1), 4);
}

delete vals;

infile.close();
```

The problem is that when reading the float array the first time, the file goes to the end.  I have used `infile.tellg()` after each `infile.read` to track what's happening.  Everything moves the desired amount until the first instance of the float array.  Following the first float array read the file goes to EOF.
I expect the record to contain 26130 numbers.  This is confirmed by `vals[2]`.  `buf_size` is 104520 which is 4 * 26130 as expected.  `tempf` is not fully populated either.

Comment: The constructor call should be `std::ifstream infile("MSFILE", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);` (or you can skip the `ios::in` part and just use `ios::binary`). I have no idea how your call managed to compile. What's your compiler?

Comment: @DaleWilson `std::ifstream` has no constructor taking three arguments.

Comment: Try again:   The Microsoft compiler has a three argument constructor for ifstream.  The third argument controls file sharing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zek0beca.aspx

Comment: @Matt, what do you get when you display the value of vals[2] after reading it from the file?

Comment: @T.C.: "**17.6.5.5/2** An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class ... by adding a member function signature for a member function name." The extension in question is conforming.

Comment: Is your sizeof(int) and sizeof(float) both 4?

Comment: @DaleWilson the value is 26130

Comment: @T.C. Turns out the constructor call has a lot to do with it.  I fixed the code to use the more standard 2 augments and that made the problem go away.  No idea why it worked for the integer reads by not the floats...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, good point. I forgot about that.

Comment: @Matt Some googling suggests that Windows treats the character 0x1A as the end-of-file character when reading in text mode. So it's just pure happenstance that you don't have that byte in your integers...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik makes a very good point.  This code would be much better if it used sizeof(int) * 3 rather than 12 as the number of bytes to read, and so on. (That's not the problem, but it is something that should be fixed for long-term peace of mind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a binary file as a text file, that is, if you leave the `| std::ios::binary` out of the second parameter of the constructor of `ifstream`, then the `read` function may encounter a byte sequence that it interprets as an `EOF`, but which is actually just part of your binary data.

At least, that is a problem I have encountered when reading binary data on Microsoft platforms in the past, and the symptoms you describe (not as many bytes read as expected, program acts as if it reached `EOF`) are consistent with what I've observed when my program read a "false `EOF`" from a binary file while reading in text mode.